# Importing python test run information into sonarqube

Tags: python, sonarqube, nose, sonarqube-scan

I have a python project with structure like this and I'm trying to import it into SonarQube:

```
root
    sonar-project.properties
    src
    test
        nosetests.xml
```

All test files are in test folder.
nosetests.xml is xml report generated with nose(tests) (1.3.7).

My sonar-scanner.properties file looks like this

```
sonar.projectKey=python-sonar
sonar.projectName=python-sonar
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.tests=test
sonar.language=py
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
#I want the details so this is false.
sonar.python.xunit.skipDetails=false
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=test/nosetests.xml
sonar.python.coverage.itReportPath=test/cover.xml
```

When trying to import project into SonarQube I get following error for all the tests and no test information is import into SonarQube.

```
WARN: The resource for 'unittests.testcase' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible.
```

Digging into details I found out the problem is that PythonXUnitSensor looks for test files on path that reflects test case name. For example test lies at path `test/unitests/testcase` and if it has name `test.unitests.testcase` in XML report it is imported. However nosetests names it `unitests.testcase` so it doesn't get imported.

I am looking for a clean way how to solve this so it can be use in CI and reused. I don't want to edit reports, I'm looking for a way to generate them properly or to import them the way they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems best addressed at the *nosetest* level i.e. getting *nosetests.xml* to report the fully qualified path. That will let SonarPython (and potentially other tools) do the matching properly.

Simple approach to that: add an empty `__init__.py` under *test* and rerun your tests. That'll make *test* part of the classpath, and *nosetests.xml* should report on `test.unitests.testcase` .

Comment: Thank you sir. Works like a charm.

Comment: Is there a reason Python sensor doesn't check for tests under sonar.tests directory?