# Sonarqube for python: Test success score not being discovered - The resource for 'tests.test_transformation_helper.TestCase' is not found

Tags: python, sonarqube

I'm using to SonarQube to scan my python code in a Jenkins job. For my build to be 'passed' (i.e. internal rules in my company) the Sonar scan must have a test coverage score and a test success score. I'm using nose and coverage to run my tests and generate these reports (nosetests.xml and coverage.xml):

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --with-xunit --exe --cover-package=at_overlay
coverage report --omit src/tests/*,*/__init__.py
coverage xml --omit src/tests/*,*/__init__.py
```

My scan report has the correct coverage figures but doesn't have the test success score. When i look at the output I get during my scan I see the following:

```
14:47:19 [sonarQube scan] 14:47:19.252 INFO  - Processing report '/usr/src/app/jenkins/workspace/at-overlay_release_uat-BNAIZGRBYSDANHOQHN2L6FCL4JRFHKJO5WZOZYKP6RAZFUAILPPA/nosetests.xml'
14:47:19 [sonarQube scan] 14:47:19.256 WARN  - The resource for 'tests.test_transformation_helper.TestCase' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
14:47:19 [sonarQube scan] 14:47:19.256 WARN  - The resource for 'tests.test_data_wrapper.TestDataWrapper' is not found, drilling down to the details of this test won't be possible
```

I found one answer here on SO - [Importing python test run information into sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812997/importing-python-test-run-information-into-sonarqube) although when I tried that I still got the same result. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the omit of your tests:

```
coverage report --omit src/tests/*,*/__init__.py
coverage xml --omit src/tests/*,*/__init__.py
```

to

```
coverage report --omit */__init__.py
coverage xml --omit */__init__.py
```

Sonar uses the test files to calculate test success as shown in the OSS plugin code [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-python/blob/32ab65a8eae21842e6759051e9f154036fe56c70/sonar-python-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/python/xunit/PythonXUnitSensor.java#L169)

That is where the warning logs are coming from.